# Simple query about setOnClickListener() of android

Tags: android

```
View  firstButton   = findViewById ( R.id.button1 );    
firstButton.setOnClickListener(this);     
View secondButton = findViewById(R.id.button2);    
secondButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

In the code what is refer to by `this` keyword whis is passed as a argument of `setOnClickListener()`

Comment: you should paste the class definition with your code. it's impossible to answer you otherwise. and the instance of that class is the "this" you're looking for

Answer (score 3):

It would be the current instance of the `Activity`.  (It could also be a `View`, I suppose).

Ultimately, `this` refers to the instance of the class it resides in.

Answer (score 2):

'this' is always a reference to the current instance, i.e. the instance to which the currently executing method belongs. So if the currently executing method is a method of an Activity class then 'this' refers to the instance of this Activity class.

More importantly, and specifically regarding setOnClickListener, 'this' should refer to an instance that, regardless of its exact type, implements the [View.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) interface (and therefore *behaves as* a listener of click events). This is because Button.setOnClickListener specifically expects an 'OnClickListener' - a listener of click events - as an argument. The method's signature is:

```
void Button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener l)
```